# Graphing temperature over time for HP iLo 4

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-proliant, ilo, physical-environment

Server: HP DL380p Gen 8, running latest iLo 4.

One sensor, Sensor #25 for the HD Controller, tends to run a bit hot when compared to the other sensors. It tends to read 75 C. Caution temp is 100 C. Critical temp is "N/A". This is always my hottest sensor.

First, **is this sensor anything to worry about?**  If not, then my problem is solved.

Second, if this sensor is something that needs to be monitored, then would you mind helping me monitor it? Periodically, I refresh the iLo 4 webpage which will give me the temperature. It would be much more comforting if I could view a history of prior readings. (Ideally a graph, but CSV would be adequate).

Thank you for your time and help. I would be happy to provide additional information if any is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a million different ways to monitor this, Use scom,nagios,splunk,solarwinds  etc the list goes on and on.  If you have more then a few servers I'd use nagios to monitor things like this.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the sensor data periodically using IPMI.
Use RRDTool to graph it.

see [here:](http://knowledgebase.tditechnologies.com/RRDTOOL-graph)

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the suggestions to graph this sensor. Sensor #25 on your platform is a system board temperature probe. It tends to hover around 70-80 degrees Celsius. It's not a big deal. These systems react well to temperature changes and as long as you control your ambient, I don't see a problem. If you are paranoid, you can set the system to run with *Increased Cooling* set in the BIOS. It's typically meant for running with third-party PCIe cards or when operating in non-ideal environments, but that's an option.

If you don't have alert management established on the system at this point, you should do so using HP's tools. At least you'll receive an email alert... You can also get this information from within the operating system.

> Trap-ID=6018
>
> The server's temperature is outside of normal operating range. The
>   system will be shutdown.

Typical DL380p Gen8 temperature output:

```
# hplog  -t
ID     TYPE        LOCATION      STATUS    CURRENT  THRESHOLD 
 1  Basic Sensor Ambient         Normal    64F/ 18C 107F/ 42C 
 2  Basic Sensor CPU (1)         Normal   104F/ 40C 158F/ 70C 
 3  Basic Sensor CPU (2)         Normal   ---F/---C 158F/ 70C 
 4  Basic Sensor Memory Board    Normal    78F/ 26C 188F/ 87C 
 5  Basic Sensor Memory Board    Normal    77F/ 25C 188F/ 87C 
 6  Basic Sensor Memory Board    Normal    80F/ 27C 188F/ 87C 
 7  Basic Sensor Memory Board    Normal    82F/ 28C 188F/ 87C 
 8  Basic Sensor Memory Board    Normal   ---F/---C 188F/ 87C 
 9  Basic Sensor Memory Board    Normal   ---F/---C 188F/ 87C 
10  Basic Sensor Memory Board    Normal   ---F/---C 188F/ 87C 
11  Basic Sensor Memory Board    Normal   ---F/---C 188F/ 87C 
12  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal    95F/ 35C 140F/ 60C 
13  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal   111F/ 44C 221F/105C 
14  Basic Sensor Pwr. Supply Bay Normal    73F/ 23C ---F/---C 
15  Basic Sensor Pwr. Supply Bay Normal    73F/ 23C ---F/---C 
16  Basic Sensor Pwr. Supply Bay Normal    75F/ 24C 167F/ 75C 
17  Basic Sensor Pwr. Supply Bay Normal    87F/ 31C 239F/115C 
18  Basic Sensor Pwr. Supply Bay Normal    78F/ 26C 239F/115C 
19  Basic Sensor Pwr. Supply Bay Normal    78F/ 26C 239F/115C 
20  Basic Sensor Pwr. Supply Bay Normal    86F/ 30C 239F/115C 
21  Basic Sensor Pwr. Supply Bay Normal    77F/ 25C 239F/115C 
22  Basic Sensor Pwr. Supply Bay Normal    78F/ 26C 239F/115C 
23  Basic Sensor Pwr. Supply Bay Normal    84F/ 29C 194F/ 90C 
24  Basic Sensor Pwr. Supply Bay Normal    75F/ 24C 194F/ 90C 
25  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal   158F/ 70C 212F/100C 
26  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal    89F/ 32C 194F/ 90C 
27  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal   ---F/---C 212F/100C 
28  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal   ---F/---C 212F/100C 
29  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal   ---F/---C 212F/100C 
30  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal   ---F/---C 212F/100C 
31  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal   ---F/---C 212F/100C 
32  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal   ---F/---C 212F/100C 
33  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal   ---F/---C 212F/100C 
34  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal    78F/ 26C 149F/ 65C 
35  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal    80F/ 27C 150F/ 66C 
36  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal    80F/ 27C 150F/ 66C 
37  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal   ---F/---C 149F/ 65C 
38  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal   ---F/---C 149F/ 65C 
39  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal   ---F/---C 149F/ 65C 
40  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal    89F/ 32C 150F/ 66C 
41  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal   ---F/---C 150F/ 66C 
42  Basic Sensor Pwr. Supply Bay Normal    75F/ 24C 203F/ 95C 
43  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal   104F/ 40C 194F/ 90C 
44  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal    86F/ 30C 176F/ 80C 
45  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal    62F/ 17C 149F/ 65C 
46  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal    86F/ 30C 167F/ 75C 
47  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal    82F/ 28C 167F/ 75C 
48  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal    89F/ 32C 167F/ 75C 
49  Basic Sensor Chassis         Normal    84F/ 29C 167F/ 75C 
50  Basic Sensor Chassis         Normal    86F/ 30C 167F/ 75C
```